# Login page issue in WSO2 v4.2.0

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I upgraded WSO2 v4.1.0 to v4.2.0 as the deployment.toml is identical, only one config was added in the new version the rest configs are the same.

```
[apim.key_manager]
enable_apikey_subscription_validation = true
```

**The previous version with all the same configurations started and made requests clearly**. With version 4.2.0 the program starts fine, only at the end in *wso2carbon.log* there are several warnings, I can login to the */carbon* page and can open the main devportal page with APIs **but as soon as I want to go to the login page on */devportal, /publisher, /admin* gives me a 500 status code and the following error in the logs (also attached startup warnings):**

```
TID: [] [] [2023-03-29 17:25:08,220]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.event.processor.core.EventProcessorDeployer} - Execution plan is deployed successfully and in active state  : carbon.super_resource_10KPerMin_default
TID: [] [] [2023-03-29 17:25:08,949]  WARN {org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.common.jms.JMSListener} - Polling tasks on destination : keyManager of type topic for listener Siddhi-JMS-Consumer#keyManager have not yet started after 3 seconds ..
TID: [] [] [2023-03-29 17:25:08,956]  WARN {org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.common.jms.JMSListener} - Polling tasks on destination : notification of type topic for listener Siddhi-JMS-Consumer#notification have not yet started after 3 seconds ..
TID: [] [] [2023-03-29 17:25:09,115]  WARN {org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.common.jms.JMSListener} - Polling tasks on destination : notification of type topic for listener Siddhi-JMS-Consumer#notification have not yet started after 3 seconds ..
TID: [] [] [2023-03-29 17:25:09,628]  WARN {org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.common.jms.JMSListener} - Polling tasks on destination : tokenRevocation of type topic for listener Siddhi-JMS-Consumer#tokenRevocation have not yet started after 3 seconds ..
TID: [] [] [2023-03-29 17:25:09,690]  WARN {org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.common.jms.JMSListener} - Polling tasks on destination : notification of type topic for listener Siddhi-JMS-Consumer#notification have not yet started after 3 seconds ..
TID: [] [] [2023-03-29 17:25:09,728]  WARN {org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.common.jms.JMSListener} - Polling tasks on destination : throttleData of type topic for listener Siddhi-JMS-Consumer#throttleData have not yet started after 3 seconds ..
TID: [] [] [2023-03-29 17:25:09,807]  WARN {org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.common.jms.JMSListener} - Polling tasks on destination : cacheInvalidation of type topic for listener Siddhi-JMS-Consumer#cacheInvalidation have not yet started after 3 seconds ..
TID: [] [] [2023-03-29 17:25:09,848]  WARN {org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.common.jms.JMSListener} - Polling tasks on destination : asyncWebhooksData of type topic for listener Siddhi-JMS-Consumer#asyncWebhooksData have not yet started after 3 seconds ..
TID: [] [] [2023-03-29 17:25:09,849]  WARN {org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.common.jms.JMSListener} - Polling tasks on destination : throttleData of type topic for listener Siddhi-JMS-Consumer#throttleData have not yet started after 3 seconds ..
TID: [] [] [2023-03-29 17:26:03,076]  WARN {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.access.AccessConfiguration} - Error loading properties from file: access-log.properties
TID: [] [] [2023-03-29 17:26:03,080]  WARN {org.apache.synapse.commons.util.MiscellaneousUtil} - Error loading properties from a file at from the System defined location: access-log.properties
TID: [] [] [2023-03-29 17:26:03,088]  WARN {org.apache.synapse.commons.util.MiscellaneousUtil} - Error loading properties from a file at from the System defined location: access-log.properties
TID: [] [] [2023-03-29 17:26:03,138]  INFO {org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.LogMediator} - STATUS = Message dispatched to the main sequence. Invalid URL., RESOURCE = /, HEALTH CHECK URL = /
TID: [-1234] [api/am/devportal] [2023-03-29 17:26:07,726] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.rest.api.util.impl.OAuthOpaqueAuthenticatorImpl} - Invalid OAuth Token : Invalid Access Token. ACTIVE access token is not found.
TID: [-1234] [api/am/devportal] [2023-03-29 17:26:07,726] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.rest.api.util.impl.OAuthOpaqueAuthenticatorImpl} - Provided access token is invalid
TID: [-1234] [devportal] [2023-03-29 17:26:14,362] ERROR {org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].[/devportal].[idp]} - Servlet.service() for servlet [idp] in context with path [/devportal] threw exception java.io.IOException: An exception occurred processing [/services/login/idp.jsp] at line [75]

72:     HttpRequest getReq = HttpRequest.newBuilder()
73:             .uri(URI.create(settingsAPIUrl))
74:             .build();
75:     HttpResponse<String> settingsResult = client.send(getReq, HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.ofString());
76: 
77:     Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create();
78:     Map settingsResponse = gson.fromJson(settingsResult.body(), Map.class);


Stacktrace:
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:494)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:379)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:327)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:779)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:227)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.wso2.carbon.ui.filters.cache.ContentTypeBasedCachePreventionFilter.doFilter(ContentTypeBasedCachePreventionFilter.java:53)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.apache.catalina.filters.HttpHeaderSecurityFilter.doFilter(HttpHeaderSecurityFilter.java:126)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:177)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:135)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    at org.wso2.carbon.identity.context.rewrite.valve.TenantContextRewriteValve.invoke(TenantContextRewriteValve.java:119)
    at org.wso2.carbon.identity.context.rewrite.valve.OrganizationContextRewriteValve.invoke(OrganizationContextRewriteValve.java:116)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.SameSiteCookieValve.invoke(SameSiteCookieValve.java:38)
    at org.wso2.carbon.identity.authz.valve.AuthorizationValve.invoke(AuthorizationValve.java:165)
    at org.wso2.carbon.identity.auth.valve.AuthenticationValve.invoke(AuthenticationValve.java:111)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.continueInvocation(CompositeValve.java:106)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.TomcatValveContainer.invokeValves(TomcatValveContainer.java:49)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.invoke(CompositeValve.java:67)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.invoke(CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.java:152)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:687)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonContextCreatorValve.invoke(CarbonContextCreatorValve.java:63)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.RequestCorrelationIdValve.invoke(RequestCorrelationIdValve.java:137)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:360)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:399)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:891)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1784)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: No name matching localhost found
    at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.HttpClientImpl.send(HttpClientImpl.java:578)
    at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.HttpClientFacade.send(HttpClientFacade.java:123)
    at org.apache.jsp.services.login.idp_jsp._jspService(idp_jsp.java:206)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:779)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:466)
    ... 42 more
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: No name matching localhost found
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Alert.java:131)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:371)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:314)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:309)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T12CertificateConsumer.checkServerCerts(CertificateMessage.java:654)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T12CertificateConsumer.onCertificate(CertificateMessage.java:473)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T12CertificateConsumer.consume(CertificateMessage.java:369)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLHandshake.consume(SSLHandshake.java:396)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.HandshakeContext.dispatch(HandshakeContext.java:480)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl$DelegatedTask$DelegatedAction.run(SSLEngineImpl.java:1277)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl$DelegatedTask$DelegatedAction.run(SSLEngineImpl.java:1264)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:712)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl$DelegatedTask.run(SSLEngineImpl.java:1209)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
    at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.common.SSLFlowDelegate.lambda$executeTasks$3(SSLFlowDelegate.java:1118)
    at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.HttpClientImpl$DelegatingExecutor.execute(HttpClientImpl.java:157)
    at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.common.SSLFlowDelegate.executeTasks(SSLFlowDelegate.java:1113)
    at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.common.SSLFlowDelegate.doHandshake(SSLFlowDelegate.java:1079)
    at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.common.SSLFlowDelegate$Reader.processData(SSLFlowDelegate.java:484)
    at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.common.SSLFlowDelegate$Reader$ReaderDownstreamPusher.run(SSLFlowDelegate.java:268)
    at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.common.SequentialScheduler$LockingRestartableTask.run(SequentialScheduler.java:205)
    at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.common.SequentialScheduler$CompleteRestartableTask.run(SequentialScheduler.java:149)
    at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.common.SequentialScheduler$SchedulableTask.run(SequentialScheduler.java:230)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: java.security.cert.CertificateException: No name matching localhost found
    at java.base/sun.security.util.HostnameChecker.matchDNS(HostnameChecker.java:234)
    at java.base/sun.security.util.HostnameChecker.match(HostnameChecker.java:103)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkIdentity(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:458)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkIdentity(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:418)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:292)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:144)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T12CertificateConsumer.checkServerCerts(CertificateMessage.java:632)
    ... 21 more
```

Running on Centos7 with Java17.

*I am also attaching deployment.toml with configs which work on version 4.1.0, the same config I use for 4.2.0:*

```
[server]
hostname = "{{ hostname }}"
#offset=0
base_path = "${carbon.protocol}://${carbon.host}:${carbon.management.port}"
#discard_empty_caches = false
server_role = "default"

[server.file_upload]
file_size_limit = "0"

[transport.https.properties]
proxyPort = 443

[super_admin]
username = "{{ apigw_server.admin.username }}"
password = "$secret{admin_password}"
create_admin_account = true

[user_store]
type = "database_unique_id"

[database.apim_db]
type = "mysql"
url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/{{ db.schemas.apim.apim_db }}"
username = "{{ db.user.username }}"
password = "$secret{wso2am_db_password}"
driver = "com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver"

[database.shared_db]
type = "mysql"
url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/{{ db.schemas.apim.shared_db }}"
username = "{{ db.user.username }}"
password = "$secret{wso2am_db_password}"
driver = "com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver"

#[keystore.tls]
#file_name =  "wso2carbon.jks"
#type =  "JKS"
#password =  "wso2carbon"
#alias =  "wso2carbon"
#key_password =  "wso2carbon"

#[keystore.listener_profile]
#bind_address = "0.0.0.0"

[keystore.primary]
file_name =  "wso2carbon.jks"
type =  "JKS"
password =  "$secret{keystore_password}"
alias =  "wso2carbon"
key_password =  "$secret{keystore_key_password}"

[keystore.internal]
file_name =  "wso2carbon.jks"
type =  "JKS"
password =  "$secret{keystore_password}"
alias =  "wso2carbon"
key_password =  "$secret{keystore_key_password}"

[[apim.gateway.environment]]
name = "Default"
type = "hybrid"
provider = "wso2"
display_in_api_console = true
description = "This is a hybrid gateway that handles both production and sandbox token traffic."
show_as_token_endpoint_url = true
service_url = "https://{{ hostname }}:${mgt.transport.https.port}/services/"
username= "${admin.username}"
password= "${admin.password}"
ws_endpoint = "ws://{{ hostname }}"
wss_endpoint = "wss://{{ hostname }}"
http_endpoint = "http://{{ hostname }}"
https_endpoint = "https://{{ hostname }}"
websub_event_receiver_http_endpoint = "http://{{ hostname }}:9021"
websub_event_receiver_https_endpoint = "https://{{ hostname }}:8021"

[apim.sync_runtime_artifacts.gateway]
gateway_labels =["Default"]

#[apim.cache.gateway_token]
#enable = true
#expiry_time = "900s"

[apim.cache.resource]
enable = false
#expiry_time = "900s"

#[apim.cache.km_token]
#enable = false
#expiry_time = "15m"

#[apim.cache.recent_apis]
#enable = false

#[apim.cache.scopes]
#enable = true

#[apim.cache.publisher_roles]
#enable = true

[apim.cache.jwt_claim]
enable = false
#expiry_time = "15m"

#[apim.cache.tags]
#expiry_time = "2m"

[apim.analytics]
enable = false
auth_token = ""

[apim.key_manager]
enable_apikey_subscription_validation = true
#service_url = "https://{{ hostname }}/services/"
#username = "$ref{super_admin.username}"
#password = "$ref{super_admin.password}"
#pool.init_idle_capacity = 50
#pool.max_idle = 100
#key_validation_handler_type = "default"
#key_validation_handler_type = "custom"
#key_validation_handler_impl = "org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.keymgt.handlers.DefaultKeyValidationHandler"

#[apim.idp]
#server_url = "https://{{ hostname }}"
#authorize_endpoint = "https://{{ hostname }}/oauth2/authorize"
#oidc_logout_endpoint = "https://{{ hostname }}/oidc/logout"
#oidc_check_session_endpoint = "https://{{ hostname }}/oidc/checksession"

[apim.jwt]
enable = true
encoding = "base64" # base64,base64url
#generator_impl = "org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.keymgt.token.JWTGenerator"
claim_dialect = "https://some_domain.com/claims"
convert_dialect = true
header = "X-JWT-Assertion"
signing_algorithm = "NONE"
enable_user_claims = true
claims_extractor_impl = "org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.token.DefaultClaimsRetriever"

[apim.jwt.gateway_generator]
impl = "com.some_domain.api.gateway.JwtTokenGenerator"

#[apim.oauth_config]
#enable_outbound_auth_header = false
#auth_header = "Authorization"
#revoke_endpoint = "https://some_domain.com:${https.nio.port}/revoke"
#enable_token_encryption = false
#enable_token_hashing = false

[apim.devportal]
url = "https://{{ hostname }}/devportal"
display_url = true
#enable_application_sharing = false
#if application_sharing_type, application_sharing_impl both defined priority goes to application_sharing_impl
#application_sharing_type = "default" #changed type, saml, default #todo: check the new config for rest api
#application_sharing_impl = "org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.SAMLGroupIDExtractorImpl"
#display_multiple_versions = false
#display_deprecated_apis = false
#enable_comments = true
#enable_ratings = true
#enable_forum = true
#enable_anonymous_mode=true
#enable_cross_tenant_subscriptions = true
#default_reserved_username = "apim_reserved_user"

[apim.cors]
allow_origins = "*"
allow_methods = ["GET","PUT","POST","DELETE","PATCH","OPTIONS"]
allow_headers = [{{ cors.allowed_headers }}]
allow_credentials = false

#[apim.throttling]
#enable_data_publishing = true
#enable_policy_deploy = true
#enable_blacklist_condition = true
#enable_persistence = true
#throttle_decision_endpoints = ["tcp://localhost:5672","tcp://localhost:5672"]

#[apim.throttling.blacklist_condition]
#start_delay = "5m"
#period = "1h"

#[apim.throttling.jms]
#start_delay = "5m"

#[apim.throttling.event_sync]
#hostName = "0.0.0.0"
#port = 11224

#[apim.throttling.event_management]
#hostName = "0.0.0.0"
#port = 10005

#[[apim.throttling.url_group]]
#traffic_manager_urls = ["tcp://localhost:9611","tcp://localhost:9611"]
#traffic_manager_auth_urls = ["ssl://localhost:9711","ssl://localhost:9711"]
#type = "loadbalance"

#[[apim.throttling.url_group]]
#traffic_manager_urls = ["tcp://localhost:9611","tcp://localhost:9611"]
#traffic_manager_auth_urls = ["ssl://localhost:9711","ssl://localhost:9711"]
#type = "failover"

#[apim.workflow]
#enable = false
#service_url = "https://localhost:9445/bpmn"
#username = "$ref{super_admin.username}"
#password = "$ref{super_admin.password}"
#callback_endpoint = "https://localhost:${mgt.transport.https.port}/api/am/admin/v0.17/workflows/update-workflow-status"
#token_endpoint = "https://localhost:${https.nio.port}/token"
#client_registration_endpoint = "https://localhost:${mgt.transport.https.port}/client-registration/v0.17/register"
#client_registration_username = "$ref{super_admin.username}"
#client_registration_password = "$ref{super_admin.password}"

#data bridge config
#[transport.receiver]
#type = "binary"
#worker_threads = 10
#session_timeout = "30m"
#keystore.file_name = "$ref{keystore.tls.file_name}"
#keystore.password = "$ref{keystore.tls.password}"
#tcp_port = 9611
#ssl_port = 9711
#ssl_receiver_thread_pool_size = 100
#tcp_receiver_thread_pool_size = 100
#ssl_enabled_protocols = ["TLSv1","TLSv1.1","TLSv1.2"]
#ciphers = ["SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5","SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA"]

#[apim.notification]
#from_address = "APIM.com"
#username = "APIM"
#password = "APIM+123"
#hostname = "localhost"
#port = 3025
#enable_start_tls = false
#enable_authentication = true

#[apim.token.revocation]
#notifier_impl = "org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.keymgt.events.TokenRevocationNotifierImpl"
#enable_realtime_notifier = true
#realtime_notifier.ttl = 5000
#enable_persistent_notifier = true
#persistent_notifier.hostname = "https://localhost:2379/v2/keys/jti/"
#persistent_notifier.ttl = 5000
#persistent_notifier.username = "root"
#persistent_notifier.password = "root"

[[event_handler]]
name="userPostSelfRegistration"
subscriptions=["POST_ADD_USER"]

[service_provider]
sp_name_regex = "^[\\sa-zA-Z0-9._-]*$"

[database.local]
type = "mysql"
url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/{{ db.schemas.apim.local_db }}"
username = "{{ db.user.username }}"
password = "{{ db.user.password }}"
driver = "com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver"

[[event_listener]]
id = "token_revocation"
type = "org.wso2.carbon.identity.core.handler.AbstractIdentityHandler"
name = "org.wso2.is.notification.ApimOauthEventInterceptor"
order = 1

[event_listener.properties]
notification_endpoint = "https://{{ hostname }}/internal/data/v1/notify"
username = "${admin.username}"
password = "${admin.password}"
'header.X-WSO2-KEY-MANAGER' = "default"

[oauth.grant_type.token_exchange]
enable = true
allow_refresh_tokens = true
iat_validity_period = "1h"

[oauth.token_validation]
refresh_token_validity = 84600
```

***How to fix it?***

Comment: Do you get the same error in an incognito window?

Comment: Yes, the same issue.

Comment: When you say you upgraded from v4.1.0 to v4.2.0 means, you used our migration scripts or did you download a fresh copy of v4.2.0?

Comment: This is a fresh copy that I unzipped

Comment: @Yaroslav Have you changed the default key stores?

Comment: @ycr yes, the separate tasks were performed on Ansible that updated the keystore, and the file name is just the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error indicates that it's an SSL HostName verification issue. So I assume the certificate you have configured doesn't have `localhost` as the Common Name(CN) or as a Subject Alternate Name(SAN) hence when the server is trying to connect with the host `localhost` the HostName verification fails. There are different ways to resolve this, take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75822675/2627018) answer.

As a temporary solution can you try starting API Manager with the following flag?

```bash
sh api-manager.sh -Djdk.internal.httpclient.disableHostnameVerification=true
```

If the above doesn't yield any results, try following two properties as well. You can pass all 3 together.

```
-Dorg.opensaml.httpclient.https.disableHostnameVerification=true
-Dhttpclient.hostnameVerifier=AllowAll
```

Comment: First of all, thanks for your reply!
Secondly, these commands did not help, I was loaded with a login page with the word "Sign in" and that's it, no input fields were pulled up. But I corrected it. When creating a new keystore, the previous version (v 4.1.0) had the following command: -dname "O=Home" and it worked. The question is why what changed, because I reassembled and created the keystore already with the command -dname "CN=localhost, O=Home" and then the login page got loaded. Why? And why localhost? On my domain, where I go to /devportal, why doesn't it work?

Comment: And now I have another problem. I go to the login page, it goes under the admin user, but it does not go under my user from ldap, although on /carbon I see that the user has been pulled up and everything is fine. An error appears that the password is incorrect, although it is correct. I had the same configurations on version 4.1.0 and the same user log in to /devportal, but on version 4.2.0 it doesn't. Did something change in this version or something else? I don't understand what the problem is, I didn't change anything on ldap between versions.

Comment: Your reply helped me figure it out regarding CN, but now have an issue with logging in by my user.

Comment: @Yaroslav glad it helped. Feel free to create a new question if you want any help with the new issue you are having.

Comment: @yct yes, I created: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75919574/log-in-issue-from-ldap-wso2-v4-2-0

Answer (score 0):

Modify you files:
For Developer Portal:<APIM_HOME>/repository/deployment/server/webapps/devportal/site/public/theme/settings.json
For Publisher:
<APIM_HOME>/repository/deployment/server/webapps/publisher/site/public/conf/settings.json
For Admin Portal:
<APIM_HOME>/repository/deployment/server/webapps/admin/site/public/conf/settings.json

Set app.origin.host to you hostname or LB address.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).