# Log in issue from ldap (WSO2 v4.2.0)

Tags: wso2, ldap, wso2-api-manager

I go to the login page, and it goes under the *admin* user, but it does not go under my user from ldap, although on */carbon* I see that the user has been pulled up and everything is fine. An error says *"Login failed! Please check your username and password and try again."*, although it is the correct password.

I created an ldap configuration file .xml in the folder ***/opt/wso2am/wso2am-4.2.0/repository/deployment/server/userstores***, this setting has been since WSO2 version 2.6, and on */carbon* it pulls all users clearly even in version 4.1.0 I logged in as a user from ldap.

I had the same configurations on version 4.1.0 and the same user log-in to /devportal, but on version 4.2.0 it doesn't. Did something change in this version or something else? I don't understand what the problem is, I didn't change anything on ldap between versions.
How can I fix it?

I leave the *deployment.toml*and *LDAP.xml* configurations that I use for version 4.2.0 and these settings worked and I logged in to */devportal* as user from ldap in version 4.1.0:

```
[server]
hostname = "{{ hostname }}"
#offset=0
base_path = "${carbon.protocol}://${carbon.host}:${carbon.management.port}"
#discard_empty_caches = false
server_role = "default"

[server.file_upload]
file_size_limit = "0"

[transport.https.properties]
proxyPort = 443

[super_admin]
username = "{{ apigw_server.admin.username }}"
password = "$secret{admin_password}"
create_admin_account = true

[user_store]
type = "database_unique_id"

[database.apim_db]
type = "mysql"
url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/{{ db.schemas.apim.apim_db }}"
username = "{{ db.user.username }}"
password = "$secret{wso2am_db_password}"
driver = "com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver"

[database.shared_db]
type = "mysql"
url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/{{ db.schemas.apim.shared_db }}"
username = "{{ db.user.username }}"
password = "$secret{wso2am_db_password}"
driver = "com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver"

#[keystore.tls]
#file_name =  "wso2carbon.jks"
#type =  "JKS"
#password =  "wso2carbon"
#alias =  "wso2carbon"
#key_password =  "wso2carbon"

#[keystore.listener_profile]
#bind_address = "0.0.0.0"

[keystore.primary]
file_name =  "wso2carbon.jks"
type =  "JKS"
password =  "$secret{keystore_password}"
alias =  "wso2carbon"
key_password =  "$secret{keystore_key_password}"

[keystore.internal]
file_name =  "wso2carbon.jks"
type =  "JKS"
password =  "$secret{keystore_password}"
alias =  "wso2carbon"
key_password =  "$secret{keystore_key_password}"

[[apim.gateway.environment]]
name = "Default"
type = "hybrid"
provider = "wso2"
display_in_api_console = true
description = "This is a hybrid gateway that handles both production and sandbox token traffic."
show_as_token_endpoint_url = true
service_url = "https://{{ hostname }}:${mgt.transport.https.port}/services/"
username= "${admin.username}"
password= "${admin.password}"
ws_endpoint = "ws://{{ hostname }}"
wss_endpoint = "wss://{{ hostname }}"
http_endpoint = "http://{{ hostname }}"
https_endpoint = "https://{{ hostname }}"
websub_event_receiver_http_endpoint = "http://{{ hostname }}:9021"
websub_event_receiver_https_endpoint = "https://{{ hostname }}:8021"

[apim.sync_runtime_artifacts.gateway]
gateway_labels =["Default"]

#[apim.cache.gateway_token]
#enable = true
#expiry_time = "900s"

[apim.cache.resource]
enable = false
#expiry_time = "900s"

#[apim.cache.km_token]
#enable = false
#expiry_time = "15m"

#[apim.cache.recent_apis]
#enable = false

#[apim.cache.scopes]
#enable = true

#[apim.cache.publisher_roles]
#enable = true

[apim.cache.jwt_claim]
enable = false
#expiry_time = "15m"

#[apim.cache.tags]
#expiry_time = "2m"

[apim.analytics]
enable = false
auth_token = ""

[apim.key_manager]
enable_apikey_subscription_validation = true
#service_url = "https://{{ hostname }}/services/"
#username = "$ref{super_admin.username}"
#password = "$ref{super_admin.password}"
#pool.init_idle_capacity = 50
#pool.max_idle = 100
#key_validation_handler_type = "default"
#key_validation_handler_type = "custom"
#key_validation_handler_impl = "org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.keymgt.handlers.DefaultKeyValidationHandler"

#[apim.idp]
#server_url = "https://{{ hostname }}"
#authorize_endpoint = "https://{{ hostname }}/oauth2/authorize"
#oidc_logout_endpoint = "https://{{ hostname }}/oidc/logout"
#oidc_check_session_endpoint = "https://{{ hostname }}/oidc/checksession"

[apim.jwt]
enable = true
encoding = "base64" # base64,base64url
#generator_impl = "org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.keymgt.token.JWTGenerator"
claim_dialect = "https://some_domain.com/claims"
convert_dialect = true
header = "X-JWT-Assertion"
signing_algorithm = "NONE"
enable_user_claims = true
claims_extractor_impl = "org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.token.DefaultClaimsRetriever"

[apim.jwt.gateway_generator]
impl = "com.some_domain.api.gateway.JwtTokenGenerator"

#[apim.oauth_config]
#enable_outbound_auth_header = false
#auth_header = "Authorization"
#revoke_endpoint = "https://some_domain.com:${https.nio.port}/revoke"
#enable_token_encryption = false
#enable_token_hashing = false

[apim.devportal]
url = "https://{{ hostname }}/devportal"
display_url = true
#enable_application_sharing = false
#if application_sharing_type, application_sharing_impl both defined priority goes to application_sharing_impl
#application_sharing_type = "default" #changed type, saml, default #todo: check the new config for rest api
#application_sharing_impl = "org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.SAMLGroupIDExtractorImpl"
#display_multiple_versions = false
#display_deprecated_apis = false
#enable_comments = true
#enable_ratings = true
#enable_forum = true
#enable_anonymous_mode=true
#enable_cross_tenant_subscriptions = true
#default_reserved_username = "apim_reserved_user"

[apim.cors]
allow_origins = "*"
allow_methods = ["GET","PUT","POST","DELETE","PATCH","OPTIONS"]
allow_headers = [{{ cors.allowed_headers }}]
allow_credentials = false

#[apim.throttling]
#enable_data_publishing = true
#enable_policy_deploy = true
#enable_blacklist_condition = true
#enable_persistence = true
#throttle_decision_endpoints = ["tcp://localhost:5672","tcp://localhost:5672"]

#[apim.throttling.blacklist_condition]
#start_delay = "5m"
#period = "1h"

#[apim.throttling.jms]
#start_delay = "5m"

#[apim.throttling.event_sync]
#hostName = "0.0.0.0"
#port = 11224

#[apim.throttling.event_management]
#hostName = "0.0.0.0"
#port = 10005

#[[apim.throttling.url_group]]
#traffic_manager_urls = ["tcp://localhost:9611","tcp://localhost:9611"]
#traffic_manager_auth_urls = ["ssl://localhost:9711","ssl://localhost:9711"]
#type = "loadbalance"

#[[apim.throttling.url_group]]
#traffic_manager_urls = ["tcp://localhost:9611","tcp://localhost:9611"]
#traffic_manager_auth_urls = ["ssl://localhost:9711","ssl://localhost:9711"]
#type = "failover"

#[apim.workflow]
#enable = false
#service_url = "https://localhost:9445/bpmn"
#username = "$ref{super_admin.username}"
#password = "$ref{super_admin.password}"
#callback_endpoint = "https://localhost:${mgt.transport.https.port}/api/am/admin/v0.17/workflows/update-workflow-status"
#token_endpoint = "https://localhost:${https.nio.port}/token"
#client_registration_endpoint = "https://localhost:${mgt.transport.https.port}/client-registration/v0.17/register"
#client_registration_username = "$ref{super_admin.username}"
#client_registration_password = "$ref{super_admin.password}"

#data bridge config
#[transport.receiver]
#type = "binary"
#worker_threads = 10
#session_timeout = "30m"
#keystore.file_name = "$ref{keystore.tls.file_name}"
#keystore.password = "$ref{keystore.tls.password}"
#tcp_port = 9611
#ssl_port = 9711
#ssl_receiver_thread_pool_size = 100
#tcp_receiver_thread_pool_size = 100
#ssl_enabled_protocols = ["TLSv1","TLSv1.1","TLSv1.2"]
#ciphers = ["SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5","SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA"]

#[apim.notification]
#from_address = "APIM.com"
#username = "APIM"
#password = "APIM+123"
#hostname = "localhost"
#port = 3025
#enable_start_tls = false
#enable_authentication = true

#[apim.token.revocation]
#notifier_impl = "org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.keymgt.events.TokenRevocationNotifierImpl"
#enable_realtime_notifier = true
#realtime_notifier.ttl = 5000
#enable_persistent_notifier = true
#persistent_notifier.hostname = "https://localhost:2379/v2/keys/jti/"
#persistent_notifier.ttl = 5000
#persistent_notifier.username = "root"
#persistent_notifier.password = "root"

[[event_handler]]
name="userPostSelfRegistration"
subscriptions=["POST_ADD_USER"]

[service_provider]
sp_name_regex = "^[\\sa-zA-Z0-9._-]*$"

[database.local]
type = "mysql"
url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/{{ db.schemas.apim.local_db }}"
username = "{{ db.user.username }}"
password = "{{ db.user.password }}"
driver = "com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver"

[[event_listener]]
id = "token_revocation"
type = "org.wso2.carbon.identity.core.handler.AbstractIdentityHandler"
name = "org.wso2.is.notification.ApimOauthEventInterceptor"
order = 1

[event_listener.properties]
notification_endpoint = "https://{{ hostname }}/internal/data/v1/notify"
username = "${admin.username}"
password = "${admin.password}"
'header.X-WSO2-KEY-MANAGER' = "default"

[oauth.grant_type.token_exchange]
enable = true
allow_refresh_tokens = true
iat_validity_period = "1h"

[oauth.token_validation]
refresh_token_validity = 84600
```

Ldap configurations xml file:

```
<UserStoreManager class="org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ReadOnlyLDAPUserStoreManager">
   <Property name="StartTLSEnabled">true</Property>
   <Property name="ConnectionURL">ldap://domain:389</Property>
   <Property name="ConnectionName">cn=readuser,dc=ldap-domain,dc=domain,dc=com</Property>
   <Property name="ConnectionPassword" encrypted="true">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</Property>
   <Property name="UserSearchBase">ou=users,dc=ldap-yayu-carc,dc=carus,dc=com</Property>
   <Property name="UserNameAttribute">uid</Property>
   <Property name="UserNameSearchFilter">(&amp;(objectClass=inetOrgPerson)(uid=?))</Property>
   <Property name="UserNameListFilter">(&amp;(objectClass=inetOrgPerson))</Property>
   <Property name="UserDNPattern"/>
   <Property name="DisplayNameAttribute">uid</Property>
   <Property name="Disabled">false</Property>
   <Property name="ReadGroups">true</Property>
   <Property name="GroupSearchBase">ou=groups,dc=ldap-yayu-carc,dc=carus,dc=com</Property>
   <Property name="GroupNameAttribute">cn</Property>
   <Property name="GroupNameSearchFilter">(&amp;(objectClass=groupOfNames)(cn=?))</Property>
   <Property name="GroupNameListFilter">(&amp;(objectClass=groupOfNames)(ou=groups))</Property>
   <Property name="RoleDNPattern"/>
    <!-- cn={0},ou=Groups,dc=wso2,dc=org -->
   <Property name="MembershipAttribute">member</Property>
   <Property name="BackLinksEnabled">false</Property>
   <Property name="MemberOfAttribute">memberOf</Property>
   <Property name="ReplaceEscapeCharactersAtUserLogin">true</Property>
   <Property name="SCIMEnabled">false</Property>
   <Property name="PasswordHashMethod">PLAIN_TEXT</Property>
   <Property name="MultiAttributeSeparator">,</Property>
   <Property name="MaxUserNameListLength">100</Property>
   <Property name="MaxRoleNameListLength">100</Property>
   <Property name="UserRolesCacheEnabled">true</Property>
   <Property name="ConnectionPoolingEnabled">false</Property>
   <Property name="LDAPConnectionTimeout">5000</Property>
   <Property name="ReadTimeout">5000</Property>
   <Property name="RetryAttempts">0</Property>
   <Property name="CountRetrieverClass"/>
   <Property name="java.naming.ldap.attributes.binary"/>
   <Property name="DomainName">USERS</Property>
   <Property name="Description">User store for USERS</Property>
</UserStoreManager>
```

Logs from carbon.log:

```
TID: [-1234] [] [2023-04-03 17:53:08,531] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.LdapContextWrapper} - Attribute java.naming.security.principal is skip adding to the environment for TLS LDAP initialization
TID: [-1234] [] [2023-04-03 17:53:08,531] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.LdapContextWrapper} - Attribute java.naming.security.authentication is skip adding to the environment for TLS LDAP initialization
TID: [-1234] [] [2023-04-03 17:53:08,531] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.LdapContextWrapper} - Attribute java.naming.security.credentials is skip adding to the environment for TLS LDAP initialization
TID: [-1234] [] [2023-04-03 17:53:08,592] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.LdapContextWrapper} - StartTLS connection established successfully with LDAP server
TID: [-1234] [] [2023-04-03 17:53:08,592] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.LdapContextWrapper} - Attribute java.naming.security.authentication is added to the TLS LdapContext environment
TID: [-1234] [] [2023-04-03 17:53:08,592] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.LdapContextWrapper} - Attribute java.naming.security.principal is added to the TLS LdapContext environment
TID: [-1234] [] [2023-04-03 17:53:08,592] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.LdapContextWrapper} - Attribute java.naming.security.credentials is added to the TLS LdapContext environment
TID: [-1234] [] [2023-04-03 17:53:08,609] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ReadOnlyLDAPUserStoreManager} - Replace escape characters configured to: true
TID: [-1234] [] [2023-04-03 17:53:08,611] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ReadOnlyLDAPUserStoreManager} - Searching for user with SearchFilter: (&(objectClass=inetOrgPerson)(uid=apiuser)) in SearchBase: 
TID: [-1234] [] [2023-04-03 17:53:08,611] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ReadOnlyLDAPUserStoreManager} - Requesting attribute :scimId
TID: [-1234] [] [2023-04-03 17:53:08,640] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.StartTlsResponseWrapper} - Closing the StartTLS connection with LDAP server
TID: [-1234] [] [2023-04-03 17:53:08,641] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ReadOnlyLDAPUserStoreManager} - Read only user store  timestamp attributes: []
TID: [-1234] [] [2023-04-03 17:53:08,641] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.identity.claim.metadata.mgt.dao.CacheBackedLocalClaimDAO} - Cache hit for local claim list for tenant: -1234
TID: [-1234] [] [2023-04-03 17:53:08,641] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.identity.mgt.listener.IdentityUserIdResolverListener} - A userID cannot be found in the userStoreManagerCARCYAYUfor the given userName: apiuser
TID: [-1234] [] [2023-04-03 17:53:08,641] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.identity.governance.listener.IdentityMgtEventListener} - post get user claim values is called in IdentityMgtEventListener
TID: [-1234] [] [2023-04-03 17:53:08,641] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.identity.governance.listener.IdentityStoreEventListener} - doPostGetUserClaimValues getting executed in the IdentityStoreEventListener for user: apiuser
TID: [-1234] [] [2023-04-03 17:53:08,642] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.AbstractUserStoreManager} - Users from user store: CARCYAYU : [CARCYAYU/apiuser]
TID: [-1234] [] [2023-04-03 17:53:08,645] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.identity.governance.listener.IdentityMgtEventListener} - post get user user list with id is called in IdentityMgtEventListener
TID: [-1234] [] [2023-04-03 17:53:08,646] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.AbstractUserStoreManager} - Post listener user list: [CARCYAYU/apiuser] for domain: CARCYAYU
TID: [-1234] [] [2023-04-03 17:53:08,646] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.AbstractUserStoreManager} - Secondary user list for domain: CARCYAYU : [org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.User@c78c3011]
TID: [-1234] [] [2023-04-03 17:53:08,647] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.AbstractUserStoreManager} - Post listener user list: [CARCYAYU/apiuser] for domain: null
TID: [-1234] [] [2023-04-03 17:53:08,647] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.identity.governance.listener.IdentityMgtEventListener} - post authenticator is called in IdentityMgtEventListener
TID: [-1234] [] [2023-04-03 17:53:08,647] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.UserIdResolverCache} - Cache: user_id_from_user_name_cache which is under USER_ID_RESOLVER_CACHE_MANAGER, doesn't contain the key: apiuser
TID: [-1234] [] [2023-04-03 17:53:08,652] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.UserIdResolverCache} - Invalid input parameters in add to cache request. Cache key: apiuser ,Cache entry: null ,Cache: user_id_from_user_name_cache
TID: [-1234] [] [2023-04-03 17:53:08,652] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.UserIdResolverCache} - Invalid input parameters in add to cache request. Cache key: null ,Cache entry: apiuser ,Cache: user_name_from_user_id_cache
TID: [-1234] [] [2023-04-03 17:53:08,652] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.identity.governance.listener.IdentityMgtEventListener} - IdentityMgtEventListener returns since user: apiuser not available in current user store domain: PRIMARY
TID: [-1234] [] [2023-04-03 17:53:08,652] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.identity.governance.listener.IdentityMgtEventListener} - post authenticate with id by claim is called in IdentityMgtEventListener
TID: [-1234] [] [2023-04-03 17:53:08,652] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.AbstractUserStoreManager} - Authentication failure. Wrong username or password is provided.
TID: [-1234] [] [2023-04-03 17:53:08,653] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authenticator.basicauth.BasicAuthenticator} - User authentication failed due to invalid credentials
TID: [-1234] [] [2023-04-03 17:53:08,653] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.identity.event.handler.AbstractEventHandler} - Validate the association is sync or not.
TID: [-1234] [] [2023-04-03 17:53:08,653] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.identity.event.handler.AbstractEventHandler} - Get the subscription property value for property : operationAsync for event : AUTHENTICATION_STEP_FAILURE
TID: [-1234] [] [2023-04-03 17:53:08,653] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.identity.event.handler.AbstractEventHandler} - Get the subscription properties for event : AUTHENTICATION_STEP_FAILURE
TID: [-1234] [] [2023-04-03 17:53:08,653] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.identity.event.handler.AbstractEventHandler} - List of subscription properties for event : AUTHENTICATION_STEP_FAILURE
TID: [-1234] [] [2023-04-03 17:53:08,653] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.identity.event.handler.AbstractEventHandler} - Validate the association is sync or not.
TID: [-1234] [] [2023-04-03 17:53:08,653] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.identity.event.handler.AbstractEventHandler} - Get the subscription property value for property : operationAsync for event : AUTHENTICATION_STEP_FAILURE
TID: [-1234] [] [2023-04-03 17:53:08,653] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.identity.event.handler.AbstractEventHandler} - Get the subscription properties for event : AUTHENTICATION_STEP_FAILURE
TID: [-1234] [] [2023-04-03 17:53:08,653] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.identity.event.handler.AbstractEventHandler} - List of subscription properties for event : AUTHENTICATION_STEP_FAILURE
TID: [-1234] [] [2023-04-03 17:53:08,653] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.identity.event.handler.AbstractEventHandler} - Validate the association is sync or not.
TID: [-1234] [] [2023-04-03 17:53:08,653] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.identity.event.handler.AbstractEventHandler} - Get the subscription property value for property : operationAsync for event : AUTHENTICATION_STEP_FAILURE
TID: [-1234] [] [2023-04-03 17:53:08,653] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.identity.event.handler.AbstractEventHandler} - Get the subscription properties for event : AUTHENTICATION_STEP_FAILURE
TID: [-1234] [] [2023-04-03 17:53:08,653] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.identity.event.handler.AbstractEventHandler} - List of subscription properties for event : AUTHENTICATION_STEP_FAILURE
TID: [-1234] [] [2023-04-03 17:53:08,653] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.identity.event.handler.AbstractEventHandler} - Validate the association is sync or not.
TID: [-1234] [] [2023-04-03 17:53:08,653] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.identity.event.handler.AbstractEventHandler} - Get the subscription property value for property : operationAsync for event : AUTHENTICATION_STEP_FAILURE
TID: [-1234] [] [2023-04-03 17:53:08,653] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.identity.event.handler.AbstractEventHandler} - Get the subscription properties for event : AUTHENTICATION_STEP_FAILURE
TID: [-1234] [] [2023-04-03 17:53:08,653] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.identity.event.handler.AbstractEventHandler} - List of subscription properties for event : AUTHENTICATION_STEP_FAILURE
TID: [-1234] [] [2023-04-03 17:53:08,653] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.identity.captcha.validator.FailLoginAttemptValidationHandler} - failLoginAttemptValidator received event : AUTHENTICATION_STEP_FAILURE
TID: [-1234] [] [2023-04-03 17:53:08,653] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.identity.captcha.validator.FailLoginAttemptValidationHandler} - Evaluating failed login attempts for user: apiuser authenticated from: BasicAuthenticator
TID: [-1234] [] [2023-04-03 17:53:08,654] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.idp.mgt.IdentityProviderManager} - Resolved URL:https://api-yayu-carc.internal.carus.com:443/oauth2/authorize from file configuration for default url context: oauth2/authorize
```

Comment: Do you see any errors in the `wso2carbon.log`?

Comment: No, there are no errors at all. Only in audit.log

Comment: Log from audit.log: TID: [-1234] [2023-04-03 16:25:39,021]  INFO {AUDIT_LOG} - Initiator : apiuser | Action : Login | Target : ApplicationAuthenticationFramework | Data : { "ContextIdentifier" : "aef9de13-dd8c-4242-8072-a3b29b659f98","ServiceProviderName" : "apim_devportal","RequestType" : "oidc","RelyingParty" : "zvZgGcGw1Mj57yosFbvjrmorGPQa","StepNo" : "1","User Agent" : "null","RemoteAddress" : "null","UserStoreDomain" : "PRIMARY" } | Result : Failed

Comment: Can you enable debug logs for the package `org.wso2.carbon.user.core` in log4j2.properties and add the logs.

Comment: Also try to login like `domain/username` as well, which will force it to authenticate only with the secondary user store.

Comment: @ycr added debug logs for this issue. Here is on Stackoverflow limitation for 30 000 characters. Try to add the most informative.

Comment: Did a check of the password. It is correct.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/252946/discussion-between-yaroslav-and-ycr).

Answer (score 0):

From the debug logs it seems it's unable to find a user with the username `apiuser`

```
A userID cannot be found in the userStoreManagerCARCYAYUfor the given userName: apiuser.
```

Hence either the user is not available in the search hierarchy it's looking in or the configs are off. Can you double check your LDAP configs?